# Developing a particular solution using a special theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not exactly sure how to apply the formula at the bottom to this particular differential equation.

$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}-\gamma^2u=f(t)\,\,\,\,\,u_p(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\sinh(\gamma(t-z))f(z)\,dz$$

> > Develop the formula shown for a particular solution of the above differential equation using the following theorem:

Let $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ be indepedent solutions of $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+k(t)\frac{du}{dt}+p(t)u=0$$ with Wronskian $W(t)=u_1(t)u'_2(t)-u_2(t)u'_1(t).$  Then $$u_p(t)= \int_{0}^t G(t,z)f(z)\,dz$$ is a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+k(t)\frac{du}{dt}+p(t)u=f(t)$$ where G is the Green's function defined by $$G(t,z)=\frac{u_1(z)u_2(t)-u_2(z)u_1(t)}{W(z)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution of the homogeneous problem is
$$
            A\sinh \gamma t + B\cosh \gamma t.
$$
Because you have not specified endpoint conditions of any kind, then you can choose any two linearly-indepent homogenous solutions to be $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$. For example, I'll choose
$$
                         u_{1}(t)=\cosh\gamma t,\;\;\; u_{2}(t)=\sinh\gamma t.
$$
The Wronksian of $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ is
$$
    W(t) = u_{1}u_{2}'-u_{1}'u_{2}=\gamma \cosh^{2}\gamma t-\gamma \sinh^{2}\gamma t = \gamma.
$$
The particular solution is obtained from the Green Function
$$
                      G(t,x)=\frac{u_{1}(t)u_{2}(x)-u_{2}(t)u_{1}(x)}{W} \\
  = \frac{1}{\gamma}\{ \cosh\gamma t\sinh \gamma x-\sinh\gamma t\cosh \gamma x\} \\
  = \frac{1}{\gamma}\sinh \gamma (t-x).
$$
The final solution is (almost) as you stated for this choice of $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$:
$$
\begin{align}
                       u(t) 
         & = \frac{1}{\gamma}\cosh\gamma t\int_{0}^{t}\sinh\gamma x f(x)\,dx -
           \frac{1}{\gamma}\sinh\gamma t\int_{0}^{t}\cosh\gamma x f(x)\,dx \\
         & = \frac{1}{\gamma}\int_{0}^{t}\sinh\gamma(t-x)f(x)\,dx.
\end{align}
$$
I think you may be missing $1/\gamma$ in your stated solution. The solution is easier to verify in the expanded form (first line.) If you differentiate the first form, there are 4 terms (2 from each product), and two of these terms cancel to give you
$$
          u'(t)=\sinh\gamma t\int_{0}^{t}\sinh\gamma x f(x)dx-\cosh\gamma t\int_{0}^{t}\cosh\gamma x f(x)\,dx,
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
         u''(t)& =(\sinh^{2}\gamma t-\cosh^{2}\gamma t)f(t) \\
             & + \gamma\cosh\gamma t\int_{0}^{t}\sinh\gamma x f(x)dx-\gamma\sinh\gamma t\int_{0}^{t}\cosh\gamma x f(x)\,dx \\
             & = f(t)+\gamma^{2}u.
\end{align}
$$
So $u$ is a solution of $u''-\gamma^{2}u=f$.